# Clicking on a hyperlink to get redirected to another html page (or child window) of specific size

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of hyperlinks on my first html page And clicking on one such link i want to pass parameters of the url to second window whose size can be modified.
Example:

```
<a href="new.html?movie:spectre&time:05:00pm" onclick=window.open("new.html","winnew","width=250,height=170,0,status=0,");">05:00 pm</a>
```

this is the link above on clicking it should get redirected to a window of size(say) 200*200 pixel displaying time:05:00 pm 
but i am getting the output displayed full screen
how do I resize the new window and display contents of parent window on it as well???

Comment: @Stewartside are you so sure your edit makes the code more readable?

Comment: @TomášZato Your edit fixed the problem but the OP made another edit and broke the code again. Check the edit log for yourself.

Comment: @Stewartside ah sorry. I thought you edited it so that the code is one-liner for some reason.

Comment: @TomášZato haha no no no, no point in doing that :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a bit of JavaScript to run the `window.open()` function where you can specify a number of parameters including height and width.

The only thing missing from your parameters is the `resizeable` part as `fullscreen` is the default.

Try this out

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('new.html?movie:spectre&time:05:00pm','pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;">New Page</a>
```

- [`window.open()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but in href part what i did is i wrote luk dis:

Comment: <a href="new.html?a=10&b=20></a>

Comment: i passed the values in href

Comment: Dont pass the values in the href. The browser will take those. Instead pass them in the `window.open` function.

Comment: thank you sir ..i would like to know what is the use of return false?

Comment: The return false stops all other js functions so it can run the window open function

Comment: thank you sir   ...i would also like to know that suppose if i click on dis link(as above) then i will be able to display some information in the same page..

Comment: in same page but on separate frame

Comment: and that information will be such that it will again display a set of links which when clicked i will be redirected to another window....